# Finding element in XML database with certain attribute value in xQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am facing the following problem statement:

For each administrative unit co-administered by two or more other administrative units, verify that:

- it refers to these co-administrative units by using the administeredBy association role.
- each of these co-administrative units refers to the mentioned co-administered unit by using the coAdminister association role.

The database looks as follows:

```
<?xml version "1.0" ?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:au="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/au/4.0"
xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:hfp="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-hasFacetAndProperty"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gn="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/gn/4.0"
xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr"
xmlns:base="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/base/3.3"
xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/au/4.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/au/4.0/AdministrativeUnits.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"
numberMatched="274" numberReturned="274" timeStamp="2016-03-29T18:12:51.630+02:00">
<wfs:member>
    <au:AdministrativeUnit gml:id="NC.MT01402">
        <au:administeredBy xlink:href="#NC.MT01310"/>
        <au:administeredBy xlink:href="#NC.MT01407"/>
        <au:coAdminister nilReason="Unpopulated"/>
    </au:AdministrativeUnit>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
    <au:AdministrativeUnit gml:id="NC.MT01310">
        <au:administeredBy nilReason="Unpopulated" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <au:coAdminister xlink:href="#NC.MT01402"/>
    </au:AdministrativeUnit>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
    <au:AdministrativeUnit gml:id="NC.MT01407">
        <au:upperLevelUnit xlink:href="#NC.MT0xxxx"/>
        <au:administeredBy nilReason="Unpopulated" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <au:coAdminister xlink:href="#NC.MT01402"/>
     </au:AdministrativeUnit>
</wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

I have written the following xQuery expression:

```
let $administrativeUnits := $features[self::*:AdministrativeUnit]

let $featuresWithErrors :=
    (for $candidate in $administrativeUnits
        let $administeredBy := $candidate/au:administeredBy/@xlink:href
        let $candidateVal := string($candidate/@gml:id)
     return
       if (count($administeredBy) >= 2) then (
          let $coAdminCheck :=
            (for $administer in $administeredBy
                let $administerVal := string($administer)
                let $coAdminVal := $administrativeUnits/au:AdministrativeUnit[@gml:id = $administerVal]/au:coAdminister/@xlink:href
                return
                    if (string($coAdminVal) = $candidateVal) then () else $administer
            )

            return
                 if ($coAdminCheck) then $candidate else ()
       )        
       else ()


)[position() le $limitErrors]
return
(if ($featuresWithErrors) then 'FAILED' else 'PASSED', 
 local:error-statistics('TR.featuresWithErrors', count($featuresWithErrors)),
 for $feature in $featuresWithErrors
   order by $feature/@gml:id
   return local:addMessage('TR.noCoAdministered', map { 'filename': local:filename($feature), 'featureType': local-name($feature), 'gmlid': string($feature/@gml:id), 'adminBy' : string($feature/au:administeredBy[1]/@xlink:href) }))
```

I am however always getting 'FAILED' as result, even if this shouldn't be.

I believe the problem lies in the statement:

```
let $coAdminVal := $administrativeUnits/au:AdministrativeUnit[@gml:id = $administerVal]/au:coAdminister/@xlink:href
```

as $coAdminVal always seems to be empty.

I have tried several other ways to write this statement, but all turn out to be wrong:

```
let $coAdminVal := $administrativeUnits/au:AdministrativeUnit[matches(@gml:id, $administerVal)]/au:coAdminister/@xlink:href
let $coAdminVal := $administrativeUnits/au:AdministrativeUnit[contains(@gml:id, $administerVal)]/au:coAdminister/@xlink:href
let $coAdminVal := $administrativeUnits/au:AdministrativeUnit[string(@gml:id) = $administerVal]/au:coAdminister/@xlink:href
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you define `$features`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, it looks like the problem lies in the comparison expression in your predicate:

```
[@gml:id = $administerVal]
```

Since `$administerVal` is essentially the `au:administeredBy/@xlink:href` attribute, let's look at what you're comparing:

```
gml:id="NC.MT01402"
xlink:href="#NC.MT01310"
xlink:href="#NC.MT01407"
```

The difference is that the `@xlink:href` values are prepended with a `#` sign. To account for this, change your comparison to:

```
[@gml:id = substring-after($administerVal, "#")]
```

Your other approach of using `contains()` failed because you were asking if a value like `NC.MT01402` contained `#NC.MT01402`. Reversing the parameters would work.

The same applies to `matches()` - although be aware that this function takes regular expressions patterns, so characters like `.` would match any character rather than just the literal period character. To force a search for the literal period character, you would need to escape it, e.g., `matches("#NC.MT01402", "NC\.MT01402")`.

Given the additional complexities of `matches()` (unless you really want pattern matching rather than literal comparisons), I'd say trimming `$administerVal` with `substring()` or using `contains()` is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you, I have figured it out by now. There was actually also a problem in the xPath expression itself.
This expression made it work:

'let $coAdminVal := $administrativeUnits[concat('#', string(@gml:id)) = $administerVal]/au:coAdminister/@xlink:href'